# Execute bash script literally after every 3 days

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, cron

I want to execute a shell script literally after every 3 days. Using crontab with `01 00 */3 * *`won't actually fulfil the condition, because it would run on 31st and then again on the 1st day of a month. The `*/3` syntax is the same as saying 1,4,7 ... 25,28,31.

There should be ways to make the script itself check the conditions and exit if 3 days haven't passed. So crontab executes the script everyday, but the script itself would check if 3 days have passed.

I even found some code, but it gave me syntax error, any help would be appreciated.

```
if (! (date("z") % 3)) {
     exit;
}

main.sh: line 1: syntax error near unexpected token `"z"'
main.sh: line 1: `if (! (date("z") % 3)) {'
```

Comment: What do you mean, exactly? How does `*/3` not work? "if 3 days haven't passed": three days since what? Please [edit] your question and clarify.

Comment: literally literally? This seems like an x/y question and you might want to actually talk about what you're trying to do. Are you trying to stop crontab from running the script?

Comment: Edited the question to explain why crontab solution won't work.

Comment: Something like `date("z") % 3 == 0` would suffer from a similar problem: the condition will be false for the four days between December 29th and January 3rd, unless that December was part of a leap year.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

To immediately abort and exit a script if the last execution was not yet at least a specific time ago, you could use this method which requires an external file that stores the last execution date and time.

Add these lines to the top of your Bash script:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash

# File that stores the last execution date in plain text:
datefile=/path/to/your/datefile

# Minimum delay between two script executions, in seconds. 
seconds=$((60*60*24*3))

# Test if datefile exists and compare the difference between the stored date 
# and now with the given minimum delay in seconds. 
# Exit with error code 1 if the minimum delay is not exceeded yet.
if test -f "$datefile" ; then
    if test "$(($(date "+%s")-$(date -f "$datefile" "+%s")))" -lt "$seconds" ; then
        echo "This script may not yet be started again."
        exit 1
    fi
fi

# Store the current date and time in datefile
date -R > "$datefile"

# Insert your normal script here:
```

Don't forget to set a meaningful value as `datefile=` and adapt the value of `seconds=` to your needs (`$((60*60*24*3))` evaluates to 3 days).

---

If you don't want a separate file, you could also store the last execution time in the modification time stamp of your script. That means however that making any changes to your script file will reset the 3 counter and be treated like if the script was successfully running.

To implement that, add the snippet below to the top of your script file:

```
#!/bin/bash

# Minimum delay between two script executions, in seconds. 
seconds=$((60*60*24*3))

# Compare the difference between this script's modification time stamp 
# and the current date with the given minimum delay in seconds. 
# Exit with error code 1 if the minimum delay is not exceeded yet.
if test "$(($(date "+%s")-$(date -r "$0" "+%s")))" -lt "$seconds" ; then
    echo "This script may not yet be started again."
    exit 1
fi

# Store the current date as modification time stamp of this script file
touch -m -- "$0"

# Insert your normal script here:
```

Again, don't forget to adapt the value of `seconds=` to your needs (`$((60*60*24*3))` evaluates to 3 days).

Comment: Yes, recording the last successful invocation of a particular program requires some kind of external data store, and the file system is an obvious choice for that.

Comment: Don't even need to store the date - just touch the file each time and check it's time stamp.

Comment: @djsmiley2k Yes, you are right. If the risk that modifying the script file manually causes the delay to reset is acceptable, one can also use the modification time stamp. I added that to my answer.

Comment: This can be golfed slightly by saving the current timestamp to the file(instead of human readable date), so you can then get the elapsed time with `$[ $(date +%s) - $(< lastrun)  ]`. If the script is ran from cron once a day, I might add some slack to the required time interval, so that if the execution of the script gets delayed by a couple of seconds, the next time will not skip a full day. That is check every day if 71 hours have passed oslt.

Comment: This wizardry with datefile actually worked, thank you very much!

Comment: the touch self solution is very elegant, will use this in future.

Answer (score 12):

Cron really is the wrong tool for this. There's actually a commonly used and underloved tool called [at](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/en/man1/at.1posix.html) which might work. at's *mainly* designed for interactive use and I'm sure that someone would find a better way to do this.

In my case I'd have the script I am running listed in testjobs.txt, and include a line that reads.

As an example, I would have this as testjobs.txt

```
echo "cat" >> foo.txt
date >> foo.txt
at now + 3 days < testjobs.txt
```

I have two innocent commands, which might be your shellscripts. I run echo to make sure I have a deterministic output, and date to confirm the command runs as needed. When at runs this command, it will finish by adding a new job to at for 3 days. (I tested with one minute - which works)

I'm pretty sure I'll be called out for the manner I've abused at, but its a handy tool for scheduling a command to be run *at* a time or x days after a previous command.

Comment: +1 as `at` does seem the better approach here.The issue with this approach is that any time you manually run the script, you add another set of every-3-day `at` tasks.

Comment: +1, but another issue (in addition to the one pointed at by @DewiMorgan) is that if one script fails, all subsequent script will not be launched (if the at is after the failure point), until one realises that the script had failed and relaunch it. This can be bad, or sometimes good (ex: fails because a condition is no longer there : it's good that it doesn't retry in 3 days?). And there is a slight drift every time (a few milliseconds if `at` is at the top, or potentially much more if `at` is near the bottom of a long-execution script)

Comment: At can send emails.... Which might be a solution for failure. atq and atrm would allow for culling errant jobs maybe? In theory you could script a specific date for at but that seems inelegant and handhold.

Comment: So have a cronjob that checks for the existence of the next run in at; if there isn't one, add one for 3 days and warn (or run it immediately, and check again).

Answer (score 3):

First, the code fragment above is invalid Bash syntax, looks like Perl. Second, the `z` parameter to `date` causes it to output the numeric time zone. `+%j` is the day number. You need:

```
if [[ ! $(( $(date +%j) % 3 )) ]] ;then
     exit
fi
```

But you're still going to see strangeness at year-end:

```
$ for i in 364 365  1 ; do echo "Day $i, $(( $i % 3 ))"; done
Day 364, 1
Day 365, 2
Day 1, 1
```

You might have better luck with keeping a count in a file, and testing/updating that.

Comment: Perl doesn't have a `date()` function builtin, but that looks a bit like [date() in PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php) (where `z` is "The day of the year (starting from 0)")

Answer (score 2):

If you can just leave the script running perpetually you could do:

```
while true; do

[inert code here]

sleep 259200
done
```

This loop is always true, so it will always execute the code, then wait for three days before starting the loop again.

Comment: Why not `while true`?

Comment: Hah! Good catch. I haven't needed to use that in a long time, I forgot it existed lol

Comment: As the `at` solution, this will drift by the execution time of the script each run. Of course that can be worked around by saving the time when the script starts and sleeping until 3 days from that.

Answer (score 2):

You can use anacron instead of cron, it is designed exactly to do what you need. From the manpage:

> Anacron can be used to execute commands periodically, with a frequency
>   specified in days. Unlike cron(8), it does not assume that the machine
>   is running continuously. Hence, it can be used on machines that aren’t
>   running 24 hours a day, to control daily, weekly, and monthly jobs
>   that are usually controlled by cron.
>
> When executed, Anacron reads a list of jobs from a configuration file,
>   normally /etc/anacrontab (see anacrontab(5)). This file contains the
>   list of jobs that Anacron controls. Each job entry specifies a period
>   in days, a delay in minutes, a unique job identifier, and a shell
>   command.
>
> For each job, Anacron checks whether this job has been executed in the
>   last n days, where n is the period specified for that job. If not,
>   Anacron runs the job’s shell command, after waiting for the number of
>   minutes specified as the delay parameter.
>
> After the command exits, Anacron records the date in a special
>   timestamp file for that job, so it can know when to execute it again.
>   Only the date is used for the time calculations. The hour is not used.

Comment: Nice, i will sure test Anacron. Wonder why it is so underrated if it can do such magic

Comment: The real question: why has cron not been replaced with something better by now? fcron exists and I think systemd is working on its own solution, but I'm not up to date with the current state of affairs.